# VS2010 - Looking for Designer Support Workaround for ListBox DataTemplate Issue

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, designer

I have a small problem with the VS2010 Designer in a WP7 project. The XAML looks like this:

```
   <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Tools:ButtonBaseExtensions.Command="{Binding ClickedCommand}" 
                        Style="{StaticResource InvisibleButtonStyle}">
                    <Grid DataContext="{Binding Gui}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Label}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Which works as expected in the emulator, but does not give me any output in the designer.

If I change the code to this, however, the designer works fine

```
  <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Tools:ButtonBaseExtensions.Command="{Binding ClickedCommand}" 
                        Style="{StaticResource InvisibleButtonStyle}">
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Gui.Label}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Anyone can confirm that this is a designer bug? And if so, any simple workaround? I do not want to change my XAML or structure my controls differently, only to support the designer.

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

There have been a few people asking similar questions—relating to nesting item collections within bindings. The general experience is that if you have items within items then things may not behave as you expect (or may see elsewhere).

That it behaves differently is probably not intended.
Try the "official" forums (http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/98.aspx) for confirmation as to whether this is a "bug" or not.

You may also want to reconsider your model structure in the mean time as you may hit other related issues. Lists in lists can also have performance issues and are recommended too be avoided if possible.

Comment: But its not a list in a list :-(
Its the normal way of creating a template for the items in the list, its just that I don't want to e.g. create extra controls during development (if I would put the Grid in a seperate control, it would work, even in the Designer). But you are right, i will ask in the real forum, even though I hate their UI and search :-)

Comment: @Christian It's not clear what your model is. I assumed that `GUI` contained a collection of `Label`s. Looking again, why does the TextBlock need to be inside the Grid inside the button? The grid seems redundant.

Comment: The Gui property contains a class which implements things like Labels or other visual elements. I know, in this simple example, the textblock does not need a grid. But normally the GUI control will become more complex, eventually been placed in its own UserControl. Then everything works fine, btw. But normally I start designing the controls on one page, splitting them up after they get big enough (the grid will become its own control then)...